# почему не работает код?Как сделать если количество итераций по времени нужно задавать с клавиатуры?

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;
using board = vector<vector<int>>;

board Move(const board& a)
{
    board b(a);
    int n = a.size(); // Считаем квадратом!
    for (auto& v : b) for (auto& c : v) c--;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            // Клетка больна?
            if (a[i][j] > 0)
            {
                // Заражаем соседей
                if (rand() % 2 && i > 0 && a[i - 1][j] < -4) b[i - 1][j] = 5;
                if (rand() % 2 && i < n - 1 && a[i + 1][j] < -4) b[i + 1][j] = 5;
                if (rand() % 2 && j > 0 && a[i][j - 1] < -4) b[i][j - 1] = 5;
                if (rand() % 2 && j < n - 1 && a[i][j + 1] < -4) b[i][j + 1] = 5;
            }
    return b;
}

void Show(const board& a)
{
    getchar();
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i, cout << endl)
        for (int j = 0; j < a[0].size(); ++j)
            cout << (a[i][j] > 0 ? "X" : (a[i][j] >= -4) ? "O" : ".");
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    srand(time(0));
    int n, cell1, cell2, numbers,iters;
    cout << "Введите матрицу nxn:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите количество вирусов : ";
    cin >> numbers;
    cout << "Введите их позиции : ";
    board s(n, vector<int>(n, -5));
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        int cell1,cell2;
        cin >> cell1 >> cell2;
        s[cell1][cell2] = 5;
    }
    cout << "Сколько итераций:";
    cin >> iters;
    for (int k = 0; k < iters && getchar(); ++k) Show(s = Move(s));
}
```

Comment: Дубль вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1238936/195342

Comment: @Harry for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        int cell1,cell2;
        cin >> cell1 >> cell2;
        s[cell1][cell2] = 5;
    } 
что здесь не так почему не работает?

Comment: @Harry как сделать чтобы вместо Enter мы вводили количество с клавиатуры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int iters;
cout << "How many iteration? ";
cin >> iters;

for (int i = 0;i < iters; ++i) Show(s = Move(s));
```

Только так все просвистит мгновенно, вы ничего не увидите. Я бы рекомендовал оставить

```
for (int i = 0;i < iters && getchar(); ++i) Show(s = Move(s));
```

Так вы Enter'ом будете с экрана на экран переходить.

Только я не понимаю, зачем это нужно? В любой момент можно нажать Ctrl-C и просто остановить программу, а так она больше указанного числа итераций не сделает.

Comment: что-то не работает

Comment: почему на количестве итераций хочет 2 цифры?

Comment: я изменил код можете посмотреть что не так?

Comment: А что не так? Все вроде нормально...